# Solve the differential equation : $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{xy}{x+y}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{xy}{x+y}$$

Is this differential equation solvable? Every method I know of is not helping me at all.

I cannot do separation of variables or standard methods for homogeneous equation or even do Bernoulli's equation.

I think it is wrong.

Can I please get some more insight??

Comment: Plenty of equations do not have solutions that can be written down in any closed form formula, but you can often proven that solutions exist and have properties, even if you can't write down a formula. You can also use a computer to show you what the graph does.

Comment: I understand but I think the question is asking for a closed form solution. Do you think that if it's possible in this case?

Comment: Is this a homework problem? If so, it is standard practice for users to include more of their own efforts, and to make sure to indicate as such in the question.

Comment: No it's not a homework. I'm prepping for an entrance and this is just a problem I found which is within the syllabus. Also I didn't write anything down because there wasn't much to write down. That's why I wrote about the methods that I looked for to solve this one.

Comment: @abiessu no that didn't help me at all..from there I couldn't transform it into a first order linear differential equation which I can solve by the standard methods.

Comment: FWIW, [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dy%2Fdx+%3D+%28x*y%29%2F%28x%2By%29) fails to provide a closed-form solution.

Comment: As does Mathematica with DSolve[y'[x] == x*y[x]/(x + y[x]), y[x], x]

Comment: Does it help to write it as $\frac {dx}{dy}=\frac 1x + \frac 1y$?

Comment: Maybe you could try finding an *implicit* equation of the form $f(x, y) = 0$?

Comment: @RobertShore: I suggested that form and then thought it might not be helpful and deleted the comment but the OP responded right away...

Comment: I suggest you add two things to the question (1) The source (perhaps the entrance exam being prepared for) (2) The techniques in the syllabus of the exam. That can help reverse the closure.